# Generics hell: hamcrest matcher as a method parameter

Tags: java, generics, hamcrest

So, let's have a list of strings and a function that takes a Hamcrest matcher and returns a result of the `matches()` method of the provided matcher:

```
public boolean matchIt(final Matcher<? super List<String>> matcher) {
    final List<String> lst = obtainListFromSomewhere();
    return matcher.matches(lst);
}
```

So far so good. Now I can easily call:

```
matchIt(empty());
matchIt(anything());
matchIt(hasItem("item"));
matchIt(everyItem(equalToIgnoringCase("item")));
```

...since all of these factory static methods produce a matcher that fits the method signature `Matcher<? super List<String>>`.

However, I believe a matcher that accepts an Iterable of objects should be accepted by the `matchIt()` method as well:

```
matchIt(everyItem(anything()));
```

So I naively changed the `matchIt()` method signature:

```
public boolean matchIt(final Matcher<? super List<? super String>> matcher);
```

But it doesn't work at all. Not only it doesn't accept `everyItem(anything())`, it doesn't even accept the previously correct `everyItem(equalToIgnoringCase("item"))` saying (1.7.0_05 compiler version):

```
actual argument Matcher<Iterable<String>> cannot be converted to Matcher<? super List<? super String>> by method invocation conversion
```

What the? So what's wrong here? Is it the `matchIt()` method signature or is the `everyItem()` Hamcrest signature designed wrongly? Or is it just the Java generics system being beyond repair? Thanks a lot for you comments!

EDIT
@rlegendi my intention here is to provide an interface for the client to add and execute predicates about the list. That's the `matchIt()` method. Calling `matchIt(anything())` makes sense in this scenario, the client wants to know whether the list is anything. Calling `matchIt(empty())` means the client wants to know whether the list is empty. Vice versa for `matchIt(everyItem(equalToIgnoringCase("item")))` and `matchIt(hasItem("item"))`.

My goal here is to have a *best* `matchIt()` method signature possible. The `Matcher<? super List<String>>` works fine for all of the previous scenarios. However, I believe the client should be allowed to add `Matcher<Iterable<Object>>` matchers as well (for example `matchIt(everyItem(notNullValue())` makes perfect sense here, the client wants to know whether every String item of the list is not null).

However I can't find the right signature, `matchIt(Matcher<? super List<? super String>>)` doesn't work for `everyItem(notNullValue());`

I use Hamcrest 1.3.

EDIT 2:

I believe I have found my root misunderstanding.

The `everyItem(anything())` expression return an object of type `Matcher<Iterable<Object>>`. So I can do easily `Matcher<Iterable<Object>> m = everyItem(anything());`

However what I don't understand is why I can't do `Matcher<? super List<? super String>> m1 = m;`. It seems that `Matcher<Iterable<Object>>` is not `Matcher<? super List<? super String>>` but I don't get it why.

I can't even do `Matcher<? super List<?>> m1 = m;`. `Matcher<Iterable<Object>>` is not `Matcher<? super List<?>>`? Why?

Comment: Great question! I'm not sure about your intents, but wouldn't a simple `Matcher<?>` solve all your issues? Btw can you tell a bit more about what kind of matcher you would like to create? You want to match quite a lot of things (`Object`, `Collection<? extends Object>`, `Iterable<? super String>`, etc.), which is a bit strange for me, probably a bit more description could help us get a better understanding of your problem.

Comment: addHi(List<?> list) { list.add("hi"); } ... List<Integer> integerList = new List<Integer>(); addHi(integerList); // Ooops.

Comment: @johv Yes, you cannot add an element to an *unknown type* collection - but if you take a look on the question, there were no such operations on the `matcher` parameter.

Comment: @rlegendi There's no difference between calling matcher.matches and list.add.

Comment: @johv: I think there is a difference: matches() is not declared with type parameter, it accepts an Object (or it used to be that way in Hamcrest 1.2.1). So it can be called and there won't be a compilation error (in your example for instance, I can call list.indexOf(...) anytime, but not add(...)).

Comment: @rlegendi I added more description about my intents to the question

Comment: Similar question about `List<List<? super String>>` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289847/listlist-super-string-doesnt-work-as-expected

Answer (score 5):

> However, I believe a matcher that accepts an Iterable of objects
>   should be accepted by the matchIt() method as well

No, that is not correct. Instead of `Iterable`, let's consider `List` for the moment. So you have a `Matcher<List<Object>>`, and its `matches` method takes a `List<Object>`. Now, would this take a `List<String>`? No. And you probably already know why -- because it could add an object of type `Object` into the list.

Now, I know that in naming the class `Matcher`, you expect the `matches` method to be read-only, and not mutate the list given to it. However, there is no guarantee of that. If indeed it does not add anything to the list, the correct type for the matcher would be `Matcher<List<?>>`, which (1) does not allow the `matches` method to add anything to the list except `null`, and (2) will allow the `matches` method to take a list of any type.

I believe that your current method signature `public boolean matchIt(final Matcher<? super List<String>> matcher)` already allows `Matcher<List<?>>` (or `Matcher<Iterable<?>>`).

Comment: I added more explanation to the question. I don't understand that  `Matcher<Iterable<Object>>` is not a `Matcher<? super List<? super String>>` and even worse `Matcher<Iterable<Object>>` is not a `Matcher<? super List<?>>`.

Comment: @JanDudek: a `Matcher<Iterable<Object>>` is not a `Matcher<? super List<? super String>>` because `Iterable<Object>` is not a supertype of `List<? super String>`. `Something<Object>` is a *subtype* of `Something<?>`, not a supertype. Basically, what I am saying in this answer is that the method parameter type you already have is as general as it can be, and your inability to pass certain things in is because those things are not typed sufficiently generally. Your matcher should be `Matcher<Iterable<?>>` not `Matcher<Iterable<Object>>`

Answer (score 1):

Anything wrong with this?

```
public boolean matchIt(final Matcher<? extends Iterable<String>> matcher);
```

Comment: matcher is a consumer, so should be `super`

Comment: Unfortunately, this matches only `everyItem(equalToIgnoringCase("item"))` (which is `Iterable<String>`). The `? super Iterable<String>` doesn't match `everyItem(anything())` (which is `Iterable<Object>`).

Comment: You are right, according to the [Guidelines for Wildcard Use](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html) `matcher` is an "in" variable and should be "defined with an upper bounded wildcard, using the `extends` keyword."