# List<List<? super String> doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, generics

Assigning a `List<Object>` to a `List<? super String>` works fine.

Assigning a `List<List<Object>>` to a `List<List<? super String>>` doesn't compile.

**Code**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // works fine
        List<Object> listOfObject = new ArrayList<>();
        takeListSuperString(listOfObject);

        // doesn't compile
        List<List<String>> listOfListOfObject = new ArrayList<>();
        takeListOfListSuperString(listOfListOfObject);
    }

    static void takeListSuperString(List<? super String> listSuperString) {

    }

    static void takeListOfListSuperString(List<List<? super String>> listOfListSuperString) {

    }
}
```

**Question**

Why doesn't `List<List<? super String>>` work the same as `List<? super String>`?

Also, any idea where I could look up things like this?

A related question is [Generics hell: hamcrest matcher as a method parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000767/generics-hell-hamcrest-matcher-as-a-method-parameter). But I don't find the answers there helpful.

**Edit**

I had to think through [JB Nizet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289847/listlist-super-string-doesnt-work-as-expected/13290034#13290034) for a couple of hours before I finally got it. So I'll expand it a little bit here. Maybe that'll help someone else.

Assuming that assigning a `List<List<CharSequence>>` to a `List<List<? super String>>` is possible, the following code would compile:

```
// can only contain instances of CharSequence
List<List<CharSequence>> listOfListOfCharSequences = new ArrayList<>();

List<List<? super String>> listOfListSuperString = listOfListOfCharSequences;

// add a list of objects containing an Integer
List<Object> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<>();
listOfObjects.add(123);
listOfListSuperString.add(listOfObjects);

// Ups.. exception at runtime we are getting an Integer where we expect a CharSequence
CharSequence charSequence = listOfListOfCharSequences.get(0).get(0);
```

So to prevent ugly exceptions at runtime it is not allowed.

As [halex points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289847/listlist-super-string-doesnt-work-as-expected/13290103#13290103) this is Generics covariance, same as a `List<String>` not being assignable to `List<Object>`. And with using `List<? extends List<? super String>>` the code would actually compile, because `? extends String` prevents the `List.add()` call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because a `List<Object>` is not the same thing as a `List<? super String>`. A `List<? super String>` holds objects of one specific type, that you don't know, but which is String or a super-class or super-interface of String. Whereas a `List<Object>` is a List that can hold any kind of object.

Suppose `? super String` is `CharSequence`. Would you find it normal that the following compiles?

```
List<List<Object>> listOfListOfObjects = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
List<Object> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<Object>(); 
listOfObjects.add(new Integer());
listOfListOfObjects.add(listOfObjects);
List<List<CharSequence>> listOfListOfCharSequences = listOfListOfObjects; // WTF?
```

Comment: +1 And `CharSequence charSeq = listOfListOfCharSequences.get(0).get(0);` would complete the example of WTFery.

Answer (score 4):

You have to change the method `takeListOfListSuperString` to

```
static void takeListOfListSuperString(List<? extends List<? super String>> ListOfListSuperString)
```

The reason for this is covariance. The inner type `List<? super String>` must be matched exactly and that is not the case for `List<String>`. The workaround is to use another wildcard that tells Java that the combined inner type should also be covariant.

Comment: `? extends List` works. Cool. I still don't understand why the "inner inner type" in `List<List<? super String>>` has to match exactly but the inner type in `List<? super String>` does not.

Answer (score 0):

Okay question asked above is different... We can understand the question as follows:

```
List<? super String> a = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<List<? super String>> b = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();

List<List<? super String>> c = new ArrayList<List<? super String>>();
```

In this code line 2 is not compiling.... So why is not compiling?

Answer:

`List<List<? super String>>` means list of lists which are super class of `String` i.e. `CharSequence` or `Object`

But the object we are assigning says `ArrayList` of `List`s which can accept any any class and every class.

So both the lists are different, and java shows this different at the time of compilations.